# .htaccess 404 error regex

Tags: .htaccess, http-status-code-404

Since a Website restructure some old URL's are still indexed on Google.
I wanted to rewrite old URL's to new but it just wasn't possible because the content was different.

The old URL's are in this format: www.mydomain/accessories/a_test.html
To rewrite, I came up with this solution which partly does what I want:

```
RewriteRule ^accessories/(.*)\.html$ error.php [L]
```

However I need to serve a 404 header so that Google will know that the page no longer exists.  I tried:

```
RewriteRule ^accessories/(.*)\.html$ error.php [R=404, L]
```

but this results in an Internal Server error.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a stray space in your rewrite flags:

```
RewriteRule ^accessories/(.*)\.html$ error.php [R=404,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

To send the right right header you can use this rewrite rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^accessories/(.*)\.html$ error.php [R=404,L]
```

**No space after R=404**

However this will only send right http status code without showing content from `error.php`.

To show content from `error.php` as well as sending right http status code do this way:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^accessories/(.*)\.html$ error.php [L]
```

And inside `error.php` use this PHP call:

```
<?php
    http_response_code( 404 );
?>
```